# WSO2 Publisher/Store not working after installed EEM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

After I installed WSO2 EEM (Enterprise Mobility Manger), I could add device to device management. But I couldn't open the Publisher/Store, all the page will jump to the https://localhost:9443/publisher/acs or https://localhost:9443/samlsso. Should I to install the WSO2 Identity Server or config the SSO for it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any identity components or configure sso explicitely. They are already there in vanilla EMM. When you go to `https://localhost:9443/publisher`, it should be redirected to login page.

```
https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do
```

Then when you enter credentials it should redirect you in below urls.

```
1) https://localhost:9443/publisher/acs
2) https://localhost:9443/publisher
```

If this doesn't work for you, there should be exceptions in log file. Please check that.

Comment: "ssoConfiguration": {
        "enabled": true,
        "issuer": "publisher",
        "identityProviderURL": "https://10.128.230.232:9443/samlsso",
        "keyStorePassword": "wso2carbon",
        "identityAlias": "wso2carbon",
        "responseSigningEnabled": "true",
        "publisherAcs": "%https.host%/publisher/sso",
        "keyStoreName": "/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
    },

Comment: After access the https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do I get the error message"Authentication Error !
Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again."

Comment: all the login page will jump to the  https://localhost:9443/samlsso. I want to know where i can change the localhost? I done it in carbon.xml config.json identiy.xml  catalin-server.xml. But it's still not woking.

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing part in EMM documentation in the SSO configuration section[1]. Hope you are trying out this VM. Please follow the steps which are given in here in order to get publisher and store working properly.

The reason which you encountered becuase of app-manager.xml file that is in the /repository/conf directory didn't properly configure.

```
<SSOConfiguration>
   <!-- URL of the IDP use for SSO -->
   <IdentityProviderUrl>https://<EMM_HOST>:<EMM_HTTPS_PORT>/samlsso</IdentityProviderUrl>
   <Configurators>
      <Configurator>
         <name>wso2is</name>
         <version>5.0.0</version>
         <providerClass>org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.impl.idp.sso.configurator.IS500SAMLSSOConfigurator</providerClass>
         <parameters>
            <providerURL>https://<EMM_HOST>:<EMM_HTTPS_PORT></providerURL>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
         </parameters>
      </Configurator>
   </Configurators>
</SSOConfiguration>
```

1.https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+Server+Configurations